# How to correct "switch" in calculator (NoSuchElementException)?

Tags: java, editor, switch-statement, calculator

I just tried to program a calculator. It can calculate the sinus and other thing (that work fine), but I have a problem with the equal button. After I put in 5+5 for example and push the = button, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456)
at Taschenrechner2.button15_ActionPerformed(Taschenrechner2.java:349)
at Taschenrechner2$15.actionPerformed(Taschenrechner2.java:172)
at java.awt.Button.processActionEvent(Button.java:409)
at java.awt.Button.processEvent(Button.java:377)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Here is the Code for my complete Applet:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.util.Locale.*;
import java.util.Scanner.*;


public class Taschenrechner2 extends JApplet {
  // Anfang Attribute
  private TextField textField1 = new TextField();
  private Button button1 = new Button();
  private Button button2 = new Button();
  private Button button3 = new Button();
  private Button button4 = new Button();
  private Button button5 = new Button();
  private Button button6 = new Button();
  private Button button7 = new Button();
  private Button button8 = new Button();
  private Button button9 = new Button();
  private Button button10 = new Button();
  private Button button11 = new Button();
  private Button button12 = new Button();
  private Button button13 = new Button();
  private Button button14 = new Button();
  private Button button15 = new Button();

  private TextField textField2 = new TextField();

  public void button15_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

    double x = new java.util.Scanner( textField1.getText() ).nextDouble();
    char operator = new java.util.Scanner( textField1.getText() ).nextLine().charAt( 0 );
    double y = new java.util.Scanner( textField1.getText() ).nextDouble();


          switch ( operator )
     {
      case '+':

      double c=x+y;
      String s=String.valueOf(c);
      textField1.setText(s);
       break;
      case '-':

      double d=x-y;
      String g=String.valueOf(d);
      textField1.setText(g);
      break;
      case '*':

      double e=x*y;
      String h=String.valueOf(e);
      textField1.setText(h);
      break;
      case '/':

      double f=x/y;
      String i=String.valueOf(f);
      textField1.setText(i);
      break;
    }

  }
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: You've presented over 400 lines of code. That's far too much - you need to cut it down to a *minimal* program which demonstrates the problem. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 2):

First some basic coding problems:

- Don't mix AWT and Swing components unless you have a good reason for doing so (you don't) and really know what you're doing when doing this (you don't, and actually I don't either). So change TextField to JTextField, Button to JButton, etc...
- Try to use arrays to simplify and shorten your code. 90%+ of your code is redundant which allows for greater risk of hard to spot errors, and makes it much harder to debug the code. Not only is larger ugly code harder for *you* to debug, it's much harder for ***us*** to understand and debug!
- Variable names should make sense, should make your code self-commenting.
- Use the Swing layout managers to do the hard layout work for  you.

Now for specifics

- Your switch code isn't the intial problem, it's that you're using Scanner wrong. Please check the tutorials to see how to use it correctly.
- Work on fixing this method in a very small non-GUI test program, one isolated from the 100's of lines of unrelated code. Throw test Strings at the method and see if you can modify the code in this small environment to work right, and only then add it to your greater program.

Comment: Do you know, if it's possible, to save variables? I mean when I put 3 in the field and click the "+"-Button it shall save it in double x; and after I put another number in the field (after the 3 gets deleted) and I click the "="-Button it shall save this in double y; so I don't have to use the scanner and have only to use the switch.

Comment: @user1247054: You should use a last-in first-out (LIFO) stack for this so that you can push your numbers and operators onto the stack and retrieve them in order when needed later. Try Googling `java stack first in out last calculator site:stackoverflow.com`

Comment: I tried it now with stack, but for any reason I get:Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.util.EmptyStackException. I'll post the code as soon as I can

Comment: @user1247054: flag us when you do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Scanner, you shouldn't re-initiate each time.

You didn't tell what `textField1` contains. Try this if it contains text in this format: "1.0\n+\n2.0" (if it's different format, explain it somewhere):

```
Scanner sca = new Scanner(textField1.getText());
double x = sca.nextDouble();
sca.nextLine();
char operator = sca.nextLine().charAt( 0 );
double y = sca.nextDouble();
```

This may just get you one step closer and pass that exception. Make sure to read the other excellent answers here.

Answer (score 0):

When you reinstanziate the Scanner every time, your nextDouble() would always return the same value.Also, I'm slightly curious why you take in the operator when you never use it.